# When is using VALUES in SPARQL not equivalent to replacing directly the variable with a URI in the query itself?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, rdf4j

Following the question at [Difference in performance between using VALUES keyword and using directly the URI in the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891312/difference-in-performance-between-using-values-keyword-and-using-directly-the-ur), I learned that using a `VALUES` clause at the end of the query is not always equivalent in terms of performance and query optimization than using directly a URI instead of the variable in the query string.

Comment from Andy says *"`VALUES` at the end is "like setting variables" but isn't the same. The optimizer tries to push the values in but that can't happen in all cases as it changes the semantics."*

Can someone explain *in which cases* this can't happen? for which query structures, and why exactly? I need to understand in which situations this technique (that I happily used for years now) is not advisable.

Note that I am not fluent with SPARQL algebra, so please try using simple words :-)

(I know this is not specific to Jena or RDF4J but I tag the question with these 2 tags since I understood the optimization of this might be different depending on the framework used).

Comment: I don't have any specific examples right off the bat, but typically, structures where this is a problem are sub-selects and grouped graph patterns - that is any patterns where variable bindings from outside the group are _not_ in scope. In those situations, the query planner can often not do a like-for-like substitution, which can result in a difference in performance between the version using `VALUES` and the version where you have manually replaced the variable.

Comment: In addition to Jeen's points, use in BOUND, and EXIST (which is a kind of subquery), other VALUES clauses, AS (BIND and SELECT expressions), and if it was a literal rather than a URI, GRAPH. Double nested OPTIONALs can also be difficult.

Comment: Also some interesting examples regarding bottom-up semantics: https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics#Other_Problematic_Cases:_BIND_and_VALUES

Comment: Great to know, thanks. Could you/we compile a list of example queries as an answer, illustrating the most common cases (FILTER NOT EXISTS, grouped graph patterns, subqueries, OPTIONAL ?)